# Why can't I get any other output from my program through setOnClickListener?

Tags: java, android

I didn't get any response from my Android App through `setOnClickListener`, and I didn't get any output on Clicking TextView. What should I do now?

My code is the following:

**XML:**

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#3ba8e7"
        android:id="@+id/login_reg"

        />
```

**Java:**

```
package com.example.rehman.userloginregister;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class user_register extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView register_reg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_register);
        register_reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_reg);
        register_reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to set the content view to another activity? Oh boy, that code is a candidate for producing the most errors in your app.

Comment: Are you trying to open a new activity/window by using: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)? This is not how things work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start another activity after clicking on your textview (register_reg), you have to create an intent.

Assumming that your layout 'R.layout.activity_main' is associated to the activity class 'MainActivity.java':

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstable create a new Activity to your activity_layout and than on your click listener write this code

```
Intent intentions = new Intent(UserRegister.this,YourSecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And please a class start with an uppercase letter